# belongs_to parent form with has_many nested form in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

Abbreviated models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :place
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :place  
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events  
end
```

Abbreviated events controller:

```
  def new
    @event = Event.new
    @event.build_place

  def create
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
```

Abbreviated view:

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
<%= fields_for @event.place do |place_f| %>
```

**Given the above...**
I want a user to be able to create an event.  When they create the event, they have the option of adding a place.  The place may or may not exist in the database.

Right now, the place isn't associated or created on form submission, but it is definitely in the post parameters.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?  This is for Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to let user fill place attributes, remove `@event.build_place` from your `new` action in controller like this

```
def new
  @event = Event.new
end
```

and remove `<%= fields_for @event.place do |place_f| %>` block from your view.